# Clear previous used Connect-SPOService users/session

Tags: powershell, session

When using Powershell to manage some customer accounts, I would like to clear previous sessions/users that were authed in Connect-SPOService

How do I do that?

I tried cmdkey /list but nothing in there refers to any of the used sharepoint accounts.

Simply clearing Edge's cookies also didn't help, they previous used accounts persist on the next Connect-SPOService login window from this machine.